# camel mybatis component only support list parameter which must name 'list'?

Tags: java, apache-camel, mybatis

when i use camel-mybatis component in my project ,i found that list parameter must name 'list'

The example below works:

```
from(xxx)
   ...
   ...
   .setHeader("list",simple("${body.OriginCodeList}"))
   .to("mybatis:selectByInnerCodeList?statementType=SelectList&inputHeader=list")
```

mybatis mapper xml:

```html
<select id="selectByInnerCodeList" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.util.List">
    select
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from MF_FundManagerNew
    WHERE Incumbent=1
    <if test="list!=null and list.size()>0 ">
      and InnerCode IN
      <foreach collection="list" item="innerCodeSingle" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
        #{innerCodeSingle}
      </foreach>
    </if>
</select>
```

it success

This route fails

```
from(xxx)
  ...
  ...
  .setHeader("innerCodeList",simple("${body.OriginCodeList}"))
  .to("mybatis:selectByInnerCodeList?statementType=SelectList&inputHeader=innerCodeList")
```

mybatis mapper xml:

```html
<select id="selectByInnerCodeList" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.util.List">
    select
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from MF_FundManagerNew
    WHERE Incumbent=1
    <if test="innerCodeList!=null and innerCodeList.size()>0 ">
      and InnerCode IN
      <foreach collection="innerCodeList" item="innerCodeSingle" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
        #{innerCodeSingle}
      </foreach>
    </if>
</select>
```

The second example throws the following exception:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: 
Parameter 'innerCodeList' not found. Available parameters are [collection, list]
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'innerCodeList' not found. Available parameters are [collection, list]
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150) ~[mybatis-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisProducer.doSelectList(MyBatisProducer.java:117) ~[camel-mybatis-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisProducer.process(MyBatisProducer.java:63) ~[camel-mybatis-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:57) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisConsumer.processBatch(MyBatisConsumer.java:130) [camel-mybatis-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.mybatis.MyBatisConsumer.poll(MyBatisConsumer.java:100) [camel-mybatis-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: for mybatis if its just the collection object you are binding, then it would be by default be `collection` or `list`. But if you want you can put the `list` in a map and then your map key can be `innerCodeList` and MyBatis will be able to resolve against the key `innerCodeList`

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer. it is my first time to ask a question here, and i am sorry that i am poor at english.

Comment: it works as you say , thank you very much

Comment: Also you can use short mapping name like `parameterType="list"`

Answer (score 1):

Let me just put my comment as an answer here:

In MyBatis if you are binding a `Collection` object directly, then it will be available in the MyBatis XML as a `collection` or `list` variable because it defaults it to that name.

If you need to use a different key, then you can either wrap it in an object having the property `innerCodeList` or put it in a `Map` with key as `innerCodeList`. In this case the `parameterType` for `<select>` would be `YourCustomClass` or `map`